# Checking multiple pages in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to check if certain pages and divs exists in using PHPUnit.

So far, this is what a portion of the code looks like

```
<?php 
class CheckIfPageExistsTest extends TestPageCase
{
    public function testCheckIfPageExists()
    {
        $PageType = $this->findPage('/about/obvusta-employees');
        $checkMenusInPage = $PageType->find('css', 'div#obvusta-employees');
        $this->assertNotNull($checkMenusInPage); 
    }
}
```

Now this test returns positive for `/about/obvusta-emplyees` pages and inside the page, if the `div#obvusta-employees` exists.

Now, if I wanted to test many pages instead of one, how can I iterate over the said links and check them, instead of creating a test file for each one of the pages?

Because, the site currently has about 50 pages, like `contact/parent-company`, `contact/write-feedbacks` ... So, I need to declare those pages in advance and just loop through them,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through them, and use something like [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) to get the path to each file. How you'll handle failures is up to you though.

On a sidenote I'm not really sure that this should be a unittest, this is rather a test of pagevalidity, that said, there's nothing wrong with using phpunit for this imho.

Comment: Oh, I thought PHPUnit and unit-testing were the same thing. Anyway, thanks for the info. I was sure I should do a loop over them, just didn't know if it was a valid idea

Comment: Oh no, phpunit is just a tool, unittesting is what you do and to go even further TDD(Test Driven Development) is a methodology. Actually what you have written is more a test of the `PageType->find` function than a test of wether the pages have a certain element. :)
I really recommend that you look up TDD, just using phpunit is a great start and with TDD you'll be more confident that your code works. Knowing how to write relevant unittests is a very valuable skill, but it takes practice.